# get sum in query with two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i need sum of Amount  from TrasactionPaymentsDetails

```
    DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = '2012-07-28'

select sum(rd.Amount) as total,rp.TransactionCode, rp.ReferenceDate,rp.TransactionFlag,rd.Amount

 from ReceiptsPayments rp,ReceiptsPaymentsDetail rd where 
ReferenceDate >= DATEADD(dd,1-day(@mydate),@mydate)
and ReferenceDate <= DATEADD(dd,0-day(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))
and TransactionFlag='P';
```

following is the error. please help

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Column
>   'ReceiptsPaymentsDetail.TransactionCode' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = '20120728'

SELECT  
      total = SUM(rd.Amount) 
    , rp.TransactionCode
    , rp.ReferenceDate
    , rp.TransactionFlag
FROM dbo.ReceiptsPayments rp
JOIN dbo.ReceiptsPaymentsDetail rd ON ON rp.ID = rd.ReceiptPaymentsID
WHERE ReferenceDate >= DATEADD(dd, 1 - DAY(@mydate), @mydate)
    AND ReferenceDate <= DATEADD(dd, - DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, @mydate)), DATEADD(mm, 1, @mydate))
    AND TransactionFlag = 'P'
GROUP BY 
      rp.TransactionCode
    , rp.ReferenceDate
    , rp.TransactionFlag
```

Comment: need sum of all transactions.. can you please help with that.. this code works fine but need sum of all transactions as well

Answer (score 3):

You need to `GROUP BY` :

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME

SELECT @mydate = '2012-07-28'

SELECT Sum(rd.amount) AS total,
       rp.transactioncode,
       rp.referencedate,
       rp.transactionflag
FROM   receiptspayments rp,
       INNER JOIN receiptspaymentsdetail rd ON rp.id=rd.receiptpaymentsid
WHERE  referencedate >= Dateadd(dd, 1 - Day(@mydate), @mydate)
       AND referencedate <= Dateadd(dd, 0 - Day(Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate)),
                            Dateadd(mm, 1, @mydate))
       AND transactionflag = 'P'
GROUP  BY rp.transactioncode,
          rp.referencedate,
          rp.transactionflag;
```

Besides, you'll need to link your tables in order to avoid making a `CROSS JOIN`, which I suppose is not what you want to get. I assumed there's an `Id` somewhere in your `receiptpayments` table, with a FK in `receiptpaymentsdetails`, hence the `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Group By` clause to your Statement after the last `where` condition:

```
Group By rp.TransactionCode, rp.ReferenceDate,rp.TransactionFlag
```

Comment: You can't sum rd.amount if you GROUP BY rd.Amount. you'll get a line for each value of amount.